# How to combine Lists through Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I know how to combine 2 lists together in C#, but suppose I have an IEnumerable of objects, each with a list. How do I create 1 huge list, concatenating all of the lists.

I basically want to do the following in Linq (more elegant)

```
//FakeObject has a list property 
IEnumerable<FakeObject> objects = ...;
List<int> hugeList = new List<int>();

foreach(FakeObject object in objects) 
{
   List<int> list = object.list;
   foreach(int i in list)
   {
      hugeList.Add(i)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flatten a collection of collections into one list:

```
var hugeList = objects.SelectMany(o => o.list);
```

or for an actual list:

```
List<int> hugeList = objects.SelectMany(o => o.list).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do I need the var, why not declare it as List<int> hugeList?

Comment: @HenleyChiu You can - `var` just lets the compiler decide what the type will be. You'll need to add `ToList()` to the end to make it an actual list.